# Find $f$ if $f '' (t) = 2e^t + 3\sin(t),\ f(0) = 5;\ f(\pi) = -10$.

Tags: calculus, integration

I started by solving for the integral of $2e^t + 3\sin(t)$, which i found to be $$f ' (t) = 2e^t - 3\cos(t) + C.$$ Then I solved for the next integral, which I found to be $$f(t) = Ct + 2e^t - 3\sin(t) + D.$$ After this I'm not sure what to do. Was I correct in my initial equations though? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

$f(0)=5 \Leftrightarrow 2+D=5 \Leftrightarrow D=3$

$f(\pi)=-10 \Leftrightarrow C \pi +2e^{\pi}+3= -10 \Leftrightarrow C= -\frac{13+2e^{\pi}}{\pi}$

Answer (score 0):

You have the two conditions given to you:

> Find $f$ ... $f(0)=5$; $f(π)=−10$

Assuming you found the correct integrals, you should be able solve for C and D using those conditions.